# How to automatically scatter identical markers over a certain area

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm currently building a webpage that shows customer reviews on a Google Maps. There is one issue and that is that there are already over 1200 reviews that needs to be shown on the map but those reviews only have a city attached to them so when I load all of those reviews in the map than a lot of them will share the exact same coordinates.

I am looking for a way to scatter identical markers within a certain radius. So lets say pick every single marker on the map and move them al 1% in a random direction to create distance between them.

I don't really mind how this will be done, be it by javascript or PHP, duriong the placement of the markers or beforehand with an algorithm that sets new coordinates one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 }
  });

  var originalMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 },
    map: map,
    title: ''
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      radius: 1000 * 1000,    //in metres
      fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', originalMarker, 'position');

    drawMarkersInCircle(circle, 200);
  });

}


function drawMarkersInCircle(circle, count) {
  var map = circle.getMap();
  var proj = map.getProjection();
  var centerPoint = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(circle.getCenter());
  var radius = Math.abs(proj.fromLatLngToPoint(circle.getBounds().getNorthEast()).x - centerPoint.x);

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var point = createRandomPointInCircle(centerPoint, radius);
    var pos = proj.fromPointToLatLng(point);
    //console.log(point);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
      title: ''
    });
  }
}


function createRandomPointInCircle(centerPoint, radius) {
  var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  var x = (Math.cos(angle) * getRandomArbitrary(0, radius)) + centerPoint.x;
  var y = (Math.sin(angle) * getRandomArbitrary(0, radius)) + centerPoint.y;
  return new google.maps.Point(x, y);
}


function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

The example demonstrates how to draw a markers randomly inside a circle.

Comment: The specific feature for the website is delayed a little bit but I'm continuing it shortly. This looks very good though and I will definitely use it somehow, I'll most likely rewrite it to PHP to simply change the coordinates once in the back-end. For now I'll mark this as accepted because looking through it Math wise it makes sense :) Thanks!